ArcGIS Maps SDK for JS: Popup displayed with wrong alignment in Mobile screen
I'm developing a map with my custom layer. Everything looks fine and the pop up. However, in a case, pop up is displayed at the bottom left/right corner of the map, it's always shown in bottom right/left alignment instead of top right/left alignment, so pop up can't be shown fully as picture bellows.
If pop up is shown some where at top, alignment is correct. And it only happens with mobile screen when I set height of 450px to the map. Do you have any ideas? Thanks
